# OutOfMemoryException, large Private Data

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, memory-management, taskmanager, window-handles

In previous series:

[OutOfMemoryException, stack size is huge, large number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543648/outofmemoryexception-stack-size-is-huge-large-number-of-threads)

I have a .net windows service that consumes a lot of memory. The GC heap is not big. Also the stack size is not big. What is big is something called a private data. Also I can see in task manager that my application consumes a lot something that taskmanager calls a handle. My application consumes 2326 handles. I believe that these handles are some windows handles that occupy private data. I can see that this private data is occupied by 
blocks marked as **Thread Environment Block**. What is that?

[Screenshot of my application memory usage by VMMap](https://i021.radikal.ru/1003/ff/c678196250c1.jpg)

[Screenshot of my application memory usage by Task Manager](http://i057.radikal.ru/1003/f9/313fcca41a2a.jpg)

**UPDATE**

I run ProcessExplorer. I have two instances of my service running at the moment.
I can see that they consume a lot of virtual memory for Gen2 GC. This look suspicios.
Also total reserved for GC Heap size is the same for two processes.

[image]

Comment: **Process Explorer** can show you what these handles are (and many other useful things). You find it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx. Select View -> Lower Pane View -> Handles.

Comment: Hi there! Did you managed to solve this problem? I got a similar one (high private data memory usage and OOM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have classic memory leak, when newly created objects can not be collected because they are referenced from a garbage collection roots.

The most effective way to get rid of such problem - use WinDBG + SOS and !gcroot command. Example of memory leak bug investigation can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/04/03/net-debugging-demos-lab-7-memory-leak-review.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: No, he'd see a large GC heap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quite a resource hog.  I'm guessing at variables you've marked with the [ThreadStatic] attribute.  You've got *way* too many threads.